# Please suggest a motherboard with 939 socket supporting AMD Athlon 64

Tags: motherboard, processor-socket, amd-athlon

I have an ASUS A8N SLI SE motherboard which got damaged. Its not repairable after being sent to the company and the warranty period is over. So the option for me is to replace it.
I'm not liking ASUS anymore. Can you please suggest a better motherboard that will fit my other equipments?
Processor: AMD Athlon 64 3000+
Graphics: nVidia GeForce 2600 TurboCache (from memory, that's what I think). Its manufactured by ASUS.
RAM: DDR (3 GB). So let the motherboard have 4 slots that can hold 1 GB each
SATA hard disk (seagate)
Please suggest one. If you have the same processor model, what motherboard are you using?

Comment: Your FAQ's doesn't make any sense. Anything related to hardware ? What's that suppose to mean? Isn't it hardware? Don't try to be very adept of your abilities just because you can lock something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy with my Gigabyte motherboard. You can see if you find a compatible one amongst their selection: http://gigabyte.com/products/list.aspx?s=42&jid=13

I would probably just take the opportunity to upgrade both the motherboard and the CPU though... but that's me :)

Comment: Agreed, replace your CPU.  For only a little more than a new motherboard alone (Socket 939 motherboards haven't been manufactured in a while, therefore price has gone up) you could get a new, modern motherboard and CPU.  It's not worth your time, effort, or money to find such and ancient (>5 years) motherboard.

Comment: Okay, I think its better to get a new cpu.